# Adding CSS rule using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wish to add a new CSS rule on pageload and modify it on window resize using Javascript (or jQuery). I've tried the following, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
        var w = $(window).width();
        var itemWidth = ((w/154)+4).toFixed();
        var itemWidthLeft = itemWidth/2;
        var itemWidthRight = itemWidth/2;

document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('figure.itemMargin { margin-left: '+itemWidthLeft+'; margin-right: '+itemWidthRight+'; }',0);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: @sbaglieri No errors anywhere, the style just isn't being applied.

Comment: margin requires units not just numeric value.

Comment: How about, instead of using `insertRule`, you use jQuery's `.css` on the `figure.itemMargin` elements?

Comment: or className, pure javascript

Comment: @sbaglieri: That's something else.

Comment: @Cerbrus That's very slow.

Comment: In modern browsers is ain't slow.

Comment: Adding inline styles to 100s of elements is very slow.

Comment: No it isn't. Try this: `console.time('CSS'); $('*').css({ color: 'black' }); console.timeEnd('CSS')`. 13.875ms for me, on this page...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing `px`.

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('figure.itemMargin { margin-left: '+itemWidthLeft+'px; margin-right: '+itemWidthRight+'px; }',0);
```

Comment: Agh! So obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you aren't including the variables in the string, try this

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('figure.itemMargin { margin-left: ' + itemWidthLeft + '; margin-right: ' + itemWidthRight + '; }',0);
```

Comment: I actually changed it just before Joe answered. I spotted the same thing and updated. Sorry Joe!

Answer (score 0):

Create a `style` element in your `head` and append the rules to it.
For example

```
<style type="text/css" id="cssChanges"></style>
```

and just use

```
$("#cssChanges").append('figure.itemMargin { margin-left: ' + itemWidthLeft + 'px; margin-right: ' + itemWidthRight + 'px; }');
```